# Which Korean words or sounds have been used as a shibboleth?

Tags: phrases

A shibboleth is (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Shibboleth&oldid=724633407))

> a word or custom whose variations were used to differentiate members of ingroups from those of outgroups

The English Wikipedia also has a long [list of examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shibboleths), but neither there nor in the [Korean one](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%89%BD%EB%B3%BC%EB%A0%9B) (which contains a Japanese example used against Koreans) or elsewhere could I find an example that was used by Koreans. Any pointers?

Comment: Well that's a new word. Hey why am I learning English here?

Comment: Such an interesting way to tell apart a group of language speakers! This requires investigation.

Comment: I don't think it exists in Korean, because as far as I know, there was no great need to distinguish Koreans from foreigners throughout history.

Comment: The English-language edition of Wikipedia mentions shibboleths used against Koreans in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Korean_sentiment#Japan

Answer (score 6):

People from Gyeongsangdo can easily distinguish '2'(이) and 'e'(이), while people from other places cannot. Actually it was a big issue on the internet a few years ago!

So, for example, Gyeongsangdo people can distinguish the following four:
2^2, e^2, 2^e, e^e

But for other Koreans from other regions like me, everything is just "이(2, e)의 이(2, e)승." You can find many interesting videos by searching with the keyword "이의 이승"!

Comment: Fascinating! I've learned a new thing today. +1

Comment: I had fun watching some of these videos - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In answering [this question](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/187/when-to-use-%E3%85%90-%E3%85%92-as-opposed-to-%E3%85%94-%E3%85%96/188#188) on the difference between 에 and 애, I began to realize that the pronunciation of these two vowels is sometimes a shibboleth.

While I (and some Koreans even) cannot tell the audible difference between these two vowels, there are still Koreans (especially the elderly) who claim there is a distinct difference and that they can hear it.

Comment: Thanks - that's an interesting one too. Unless they have additional information (e.g. while sitting in a 보신탕집), they can probably only hear the difference between 개고기 and 게고기 if someone pronounces these differently, which brings us right back to the potential use as a shibboleth. Anyone got a recording where the two are (said to be) pronounced differently?